# TypeError: accountService.getMedia is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, typeerror

I have a function in my accountService which is not defined for some reason from my accountController. I use the exact same method with a different service, which works fine.

**account.controller.js:**

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('AccountController', AccountController);

AccountController.$inject = ['$scope', 'authService', 'accountService'];

function AccountController($scope, authService, accountService) {
     $scope.logOut = function () {
        authService.logout();
    };

     $scope.gM = function () {
        accountService.getMedia();
    };
}
}());
```

**account.service.js:**

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .service('accountService', accountService);

accountService.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

function accountService($rootScope) {
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://thomas96.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        "processData": false,
        "data": "{ \"client_id\": \"***\", \"client_secret\": \"***\", \"audience\": \"https://thomas96.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/\", \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\" }"
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        localStorage.setItem('auth0_token', response.access_token);
    });

    var sett = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://thomas96.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/users/" + localStorage.getItem('user_id'),
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer ***"
        }
    };

    $.ajax(sett).done(function (response) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.identities[0].access_token);
    });

    function getMedia() {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + localStorage.getItem('userID') + "/media/recent/?access_token=" + localStorage.getItem('token'),
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "callback",
            jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
    }
}
})();
```

I'm building an ionic app with auth0 and angular on my phone using chrome remote debug.

I just copied the authService(which was from the auth0 sample) and edited the names to accountService. I don't get it....

Answer (score 0):

you should place
`this.getMedia = getMedia` in your service, service function = constructor function, it just construct service object.

```
function accountService($rootScope) {
   this.getMedia = getMedia; ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Where in my service does that go?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my I fee stupid now, apparently I forgot to return the service function x)